# Android ClassCastException when using Preferences.getString

Tags: android, preferences, classcastexception

I'm making a Live Wallpaper and attempting to add some user preferences. If I have this:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    drawType = prefs.getString("drawtype", "0");
}
```

I get a ClassCastException upon running the app on a completely unrelated line:

```
Line front = (Line) polyList.get(polyList.size()-1);
```

If I comment out the line beginning with "drawType =" I get no exceptions and the app works fine (albeit without the user settings doing anything).

Can anybody explain this at all, it doesn't seem to make any sense. If you need more parts of my code I'm happy to provide them. Thanks.

EDIT: Not sure how to get a stack trace, so at the risk of being unhelpful, here is my logcat:

```
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nickavv.linear.Line
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at com.nickavv.linear.Wallpaper.draw(Wallpaper.java:127)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at com.nickavv.linear.Wallpaper$WallEngine.drawFrame(Wallpaper.java:95)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at com.nickavv.linear.Wallbaser$AnimationEngine.onSurfaceChanged(Wallbaser.java:45)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.updateSurface(WallpaperService.java:558)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.attach(WallpaperService.java:606)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:817)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-01 21:45:26.934: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4264):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: that's the stack trace we're looking for.  Next request - can you show us the code for the referenced lines, like Wallpaper.java:127? Is that the one of the lines you already posted? Can you see (print) what value the system is trying to cast?

Comment: Line 127 is the second line I posted, Line front = (Line) polyList.get(polyList.size()-1);. polyList.get() returns a Polygon, which line extends. Like I said, when the preference is not saved into drawType the cast happens successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My roommate and I took a fresh look over the code and "played computer" as it were. We solved it by the fact that my ArrayList wasn't being cleared of the old "Line"s before attempting to fill it with "Triangle"s, thus the casting error. I feel both stupid and relieved at the same time, as it always it. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your stating that this is a completely unrelated line, I suggest setting drawType specifically to the same string that is in your prefs.

if it still fails, I'd have to think that polyList is getting trampled by at least a side-effect of drawType.

if it succeeds, then log what you're getting back from prefs.getString(...) and ensure that it is what you expect.

Comment: When I set drawType to either of its potential values ("0" or "1") by hand it works exactly as expected. When I Log prefs.getString(..) it returns "0" or "1" depending on which preference item I choose.

Comment: Two more thoughts... what is polyList.get(polyList.size()-1).getClass().getName())?  It sounds like some memory is getting corrupted somewhere and calling prefs.getString() happens to hide the problem.  Watch for native library calls, and memory buffer issues.